# Adding hyperlink into mailbody in SSIS

Tags: c#, email, ssis

I am working in a SSIS project.
I have used send mail task in my project to automatically send mail to the recipients.
and a script task to obtain the mail body and subject.
In the body of the mail I am supposed to include a hyperlink(that is link to the path where the file is stored).

The directory name of the link contains space. So whenever I receive the mail in my outlook the link breaks because of the space.
So i included `<file:\\SHARED\\EVERYONE\\Daily sail Details\\Daily report>`
This works fine but it even displays `<` and `>` along with the link, Which should not be there.

Body of the mail should look like this.

> Good Morning
>
> You can find the report in the following location.
>
> \\SHARED\EVERYONE\Daily sail Details\Daily report

My code for is as follows..

```
String MailSubject = "Sail Reports";
String MailBody = String.Empty;
MailBody = "\n\n";
MailBody += "Good Morning All,\n\n";
MailBody += "You can find the report in the following location.: \n\n";
MailBody += "";
MailBody += "<file:\\SHARED\\EVERYONE\\Daily sail Details\\Daily report>";
MailBody += "\n";
Dts.Variables["User::MailSubject"].Value = MailSubject;
Dts.Variables["User::MailMessage"].Value = MailBody;
```

Please anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
MailBody +=  strhtml + "\n\nYou can find the report in the following location.
                    :<a href=\""+Link+"\">here</ID></a>";
```

OR

```
MailBody += "You can find the report in the following location.:<a href=\""+Link+"\">";
```

check this example by replacing , hope so it will work !